# Bad value for type double for date interval

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I was trying to get the difference between two dates in postgress,

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(f_time)-TO_TIMESTAMP(s_time),date from my_table where tId='txt' group by s_time,date;
```

I could get the result in pgAdmin and the datatype for the same as `interval`.

In java, I am getting the following exception.

```
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) Bad value for type double : 00:16:40
[stderr] (default task-2) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
[stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at .services..(.java:34)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at .$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.(Unknown Source)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606).
```

Can I change the datatype to text?

Comment: What are the actual type and the actual values of `f_time` and `s_time`?

Comment: both are of `bigint` type

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this by casting the datatype to `text` as follows,

```
cast (((TO_TIMESTAMP(f_time))-(TO_TIMESTAMP(s_time))) as text)
```